# Why won't zombie villager kid take the golden apple?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I succesfully transformed a zombie villager kid into normal kid. However, sunce my first success, any further attempts fail.

What I do: with an armor on (or with care) I make a zombie kid follow me to a safe place, where I splash it with potion. When I (try to) give it an apple. If I succeded, color of bubbles aroud zombie changed.

But with the last 3 zombies I've found, I have that problem that clicking them with a golden apple has totally no effect - the eating animation attempts to start instead.

### About baby zombies

If you didn't read wiki, here are some important facts:

- Zombie kid can spawn anywhere in the overworld given sufficient light conditions
- Zombie kid can also spawn from dead baby villager
- They can be cured the same way adult zombie villagers are being cured
- They can climb ladders, but they didn't seem to be able to climb vines

### Notes:

1. <del>There is no (**NO!**) difference between zombie kid that has naturally spawned and zombie kid that has risen from dead villager kid.</del> [Read the wiki!](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie#Baby_Zombies) (yeah, read it anyway)
2. Abovementioned behavior may be a result of a **bug**. However, I'm still curious if someone else had the same problem.

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of the zombies you're not managing to cure and their surroundings?

Comment: Are you sure it's a zombie *villager* kid and not just a zombie kid? The latter has no nose, just like the adult version. Also, there are two types of golden apple. Be sure you are using the cheaper, non-glowy one.

Comment: Note that zombie villager kids never spawn (unlike the adults). They are only produced when a zombie kills a village kid. If you "found" these ones, they're probably regular zombie kids. (This is one thing I want to confirm by asking for a screenshot.)

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have cured one zombie kid before. There is no village nearby, so it HAD to be a regular, naturally spawned zombie kid. This former zombie kid is now safelly barred and has grown up to become priest.

Comment: @gnovice There is no difference between baby zombie and baby villager zombie. I used the right apple, but thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @TomášZato There *is* a difference between [baby zombies](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/File:Baby_Zombie.PNG) and [baby zombie villagers](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/File:Baby_Zombie_Villager.png).

Comment: Ok. Not a technical difference. There is surelly a difference between black and white horse. Do you think it is relevant at this moment?

Comment: @TomášZato Very. I've done some testing, and have a screenshot for you I will put in an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The baby zombie you cured before was a baby *villager* zombie. Normal baby zombies can't be cured.

Here are two adorable baby zombies, one a villager and one a non-villager. I've hit them with a weakness potion and offered them both <strike>cookies</strike> golden apples. Only the baby villager zombie accepted the apple, as you can see by the dark red spirals around that one compared to the black spirals around the one on the right:

[image: A baby villager zombie and a baby zombie. The baby villager zombie is in the process of being cured.]

While I was writing this answer up, Harold (the baby villager zombie) had a complete recovery and is now ready to grow up and become a productive member of testificate society:

[image: The cured baby villager zombie is now a normal baby villager.]

### Technical details

The NBT data for zombies contains two relevant flags: `IsBaby` and `IsVillager`. A baby villager zombie is exactly like a normal baby zombie except that it has `IsVillager: true` while the normal baby zombie has `IsVillager: false`.

Since the code for curing tests for `IsVillager: true`, the curing code is skipped if you try to cure a zombie that has `IsVillager: false`. This makes normal baby zombies incurable.

### Where did the baby villager zombie come from?

It's commonly believed that baby villager zombies can only be created by a zombie killing a baby villager. I thought so myself, but this is apparently not true!

Digging through the decompiled game code provided by MCP, this is the line that controls what kind of zombie spawns:

```
par1EntityLivingData1 = new EntityZombieGroupData(this, this.worldObj.rand.nextFloat() < 0.05F, this.worldObj.rand.nextFloat() < 0.05F, (EntityZombieINNER1)null);
```

Notice the two calls to `rand.nextFloat() < 0.05F`. Those are what ultimately set `IsBaby` and `IsVillager`. The first call sets `IsBaby` true in 5% of zombies, while the second call sets `IsVillager` true in 5% of zombies. Notice that neither depends on the other.

The spawning probabilities in combination:

```
                   | Non-baby |    Baby
                   |   (95%)  |    (5%)
-------------------+----------+---------+
Non-villager (95%) |  90.25%  |   4.75% |
-------------------+----------+---------+
Villager     ( 5%) |   4.75%  |   0.25% |
-------------------+----------+---------+
```

So in summary, the chance of a zombie spawning for each type is:

```
Zombie type      Spawn chance (%)
-----------------------------
Normal            90.25
Baby               4.75
Villager           4.75
Baby Villager      0.25
```

Your baby villager zombie was likely a very rare 0.25% zombie spawn. You were very lucky to find it and catch it!

Comment: That convinced me. How would a baby villager zombie appear near my house is now a mystery. Anyway, thank you for writing this up with all nice screenshots. I think wiki should be updated so that nobody else will get confused like I did.

Comment: Oh, maybe it just can really spawn a baby villager zombie. I did not notice the nose in all the rush to get golden apples without getting killed.

Comment: @TomášZato I've been digging through the code and it does appear that baby villager zombies can spawn naturally! The chance is just very, very low. You were very lucky!

Comment: This is a really good answer, @SevenSidedDie - thanks for putting the effort in to be so thorough!

Comment: @shanodin Thank you! I *needed* to dig into this to finally put my curiosity about baby zombie villagers to rest. ;)

Comment: The "technical details" is mostly out of date by now (Zombie Villagers are separate entities, not defined by NBT, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Only baby zombie villagers can be cured,not normal ones. Just make sure you give him a normal golden apple,not an enchanted one,otherwise called a Notch Apple.